# Tab issue in angularjs popup

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS popups dialog to display popups. But if there is any combination of inputs and buttons then after input fields, tab goes back to url instead of button.

It would be helpful for me if I can have tab that comes first in my input fields and then to my buttons and again goes back to input fields.

I am thanking in advance if anyone takes the initiative to answer my question.

Comment: You might have to listen to `keydown` event and control tab orders yourself.

Comment: Hi runTarm...Can you make your view more specific, so that I can get it done in my application.